# Centos 6.3 PERL CGI selinux file read access

Tags: perl, apache-2.2, cgi, centos, selinux

I have a CGI script called index.cgi

It is trying to read a log file called `10.128.0.242.2012.sep.20.downloaded.txt` under the path `/var/log/trafcount/`

It appears that it is being blocked by selinux.

The audit log shows something like

> type=AVC msg=audit(1348158321.873:1472116): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=11620 comm="index.cgi" name="10.128.0.242.2012.sep.20.downloaded.txt" dev=dm-0 ino=395264 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0 tclass=file

How can I allow this script full access to all files under /var/log/trafcount ?

Comment: this looks like an apache config issue

Comment: Thanks, I will try over at Server Fault.  I am pretty sure its not an apache config as the script is running and doing everything its supposed to expect being able to open and read the log file.

Answer (score 2):

One way is with the 'chcon' command with the following:

```
chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_content_t /var/log/trafcount
```

This will get you access across reboots, but not across SELinux relabelings. In the long run, I'd suggest creating a custom type and creating a rule for that in SELinux so that both /var/log and Apache can happily continue to use it.

Source: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux (Lots of great stuff on SELinux under CentOS in there)